# jQuery editable plugin and jquery datatable not working together

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have an html table which is configured with jQuery editable plugin. Later I configured jQuery datatable with the same. After that the editable plugin is not working.

```
$('#user_list_table').DataTable();
$('.editable').editable();
```

Please give me some suggestions

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use editable with Datatable but you should use `inline-editing` of datatable.

**[check demo here](https://editor.datatables.net/examples/inline-editing/simple)**

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure $('.editable').length>0, ie, that is present in the dom.
If its inside datatable the initialize editable in [rowcallback](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/callbacks).